# Map to NSDateComponents is Restkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, restkit

I have an object with an `NSDateComponents *` property that I would like RestKit to map service responses to. The service response returns dates like this: `2011-12-26T00:00:00Z`. The only solution I can come up with so far is mapping to a separate string property on the model, which creates the `NSDateComponents *` object manually. Something like this:

In the object mapping:

```
[objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"serviceDate" toAttribute:@"serviceDateString"]
```

And in my model implementation (assume formatter and components are defined elsewhere):

```
- (void)setServiceDateString:(NSString *)serviceDateString {
    _serviceDateString = serviceDateString;
    NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString:serviceDateString;
    self.serviceDate = [[NSCalendar defaultCalendar] components:units fromDate:date];
}
```

This seems clunky and not reusable. Does anyone know of a smarter way?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask RestKit to do the date formatted stage for you by making the property an `NSDate` instead of `NSString`, but you can't map direct to `NSDateComponents (or at least not without modifying RestKit).